# how to copy files using TTY teminal from one pc to another connected through same home network

Tags: tty, history, file-transfer

In my academic lab my friend copied files from one computer to another that were serially connected using the tty4.  How could he have done this if there was no internet and he didn't install any new software?

Comment: uucp ? kermit ? welcome back to the futur !

Comment: Or `cu`! But it was likely done with `minicom`.

Comment: PPP ? (or SLIP if we're really heading back to the future). Or even good old `cat`.